# How do I read XML nodes from FTL and iterate through them

Tags: freemarker

I am fairly new to FTL and have stuck on a problem. I have to read an XML from the FTL code and then iterate through it to display the data. The problem is there isn't much documentation  available over the internet for FTL and I am not able to conclude how to achieve this. Below is the sample code which I have written, please let me know what am I doing wrong.

**XML FILE**

```
<response status="success">
<threads>
<thread type="thread" href="/threads/id/4999">
<id type="int">4999</id>
<subject type="string">
Testing of the XML and FTL 1
</subject>
<message_rating type="float">0.0</message_rating>
<thread type="thread" href="/threads/id/4999"/>
<last_edit_time type="date_time">2013-10-01T14:08:04+00:00</last_edit_time>
<last_edit_author type="user" href="/users/id/149">
</last_edit_author>
<labels/>
<board type="board" href="/boards/id/10031"/>
<views>
<count type="int">1</count>
</views>
</linear>
<read>
<count type="int">1</count>
</read>
<count type="int">1</count>

</thread>
<thread type="thread" href="/threads/id/4999">
<id type="int">4998</id>
<subject type="string">
Testing of the XML and FTL 2
</subject>
<message_rating type="float">1.0</message_rating>
<thread type="thread" href="/threads/id/4999"/>
<last_edit_time type="date_time">2013-10-02T14:08:04+00:00</last_edit_time>
<last_edit_author type="user" href="/users/id/149">
</last_edit_author>
<labels/>
<board type="board" href="/boards/id/10031"/>
<views>
<count type="int">2</count>
</views>
</linear>
<read>
<count type="int">1</count>
</read>
<count type="int">1</count>

</thread>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
</threads>
</response>
```

I am making a REST call to which returns the above XML, and the FTL code which I have written is below.

With FTL response, I need to get the Subject, Views Count, and Board URL.

```
<#assign active_board = restadmin("/boards/id/10031/threads")>

<!-- I AM NOT SURE HOW TO ITERATE THORUGH THE XML AND GET THE LIST OF ABOVE MENTIONED THINGS I NEED AND DISPLAY IT ON FRONT END -->

 <#assign message_list = restadmin("/threads/id/4999").thread.messages> <!--THIS IS ANOTHER REST CALL-->
        <#assign count = message_list.topic.kudos.count?number>
        <#list message_list.linear.message as m>
            <# count = count+m.kudos.count>
        </#list>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly you stuck. Have you red http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui.html for example? Is `restadmin` something that's already exists, or that's what you try to implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to read the XML from FTL code. This http://freemarker.org/docs/xgui_expose_dom.html helped a lot. I am now able to read all the necessary details from XML as required.

The issue was that I did not provide the parent node to start of with. Following query worked.

```
<#assign threads = restadmin("/boards/id/${coreNode.id}/threads?restapi.response_style=view&page_size=10&page=15").threads/>
```

I don't know for how many this would be helpful but I am posting this answer just because there is too little documentation available for FTL.